# ModernCV does not display gitlab icon only in classic style

Tags: moderncv

MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\name{Short}{LongName}
\email{asdf@gmail.com}
\phone[mobile]{+1123456789}
 \homepage{www.johndoe.com}
\social[linkedin]{asdf}
 \social[twitter]{asdf}
\social[github]{asdf}
\social[gitlab]{asdf}

\begin{document}
    \makecvtitle
\end{document}
```

But it works for all other styles - casual, banking, oldstyle, fancy.

My system is Arch Linux and my editor is TexStudio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `classic` style you can enter the Gitlab icon and link using the three-argument version of `\social`, with a second optional argument for the full url.

The icons in the `classic` style are found in the `marvosym` package, whereas the other styles use `fontawesome` for the icons. Marvosym does not have a Gitlab icon, so if you want this icon in the `classic` style then you need to load `fontawesome` and define the icon command for `moderncv`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
% load fontawesome icons
\usepackage{fontawesome}
% set the moderncv command for the Gitlab icon
% create command if it does not exist
\providecommand*{\gitlabsocialsymbol}{}
% set command to \faGitlab from fontawesome
\renewcommand*{\gitlabsocialsymbol}{{\scriptsize\faGitlab}~}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\name{Short}{LongName}
\email{asdf@gmail.com}
\phone[mobile]{+1123456789}
 \homepage{www.johndoe.com}
\social[linkedin]{asdf}
\social[twitter]{asdf}
\social[github]{asdfhub}
% set full url for the link
\social[gitlab][www.gitlab.com/asdflab]{asdflab}

\begin{document}
    \makecvtitle
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: This is amazing. Thank you. :) Just FYI, `\newcommand` gave me an error - `Command \gitlabsocialsymbol already defined. ...tlabsocialsymbol}{{\scriptsize\faGitlab}~}` I fixed it using `\renewcommand`

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I've edited to answer to work both when then command is initially undefined and if it was defined before.